# How to convert endianness- as array of bits

Tags: c++, endianness

I'm looking to convert a value from little-endian to big-endian (and vice versa). I have the value expressed as an array of bits, rather than as a single integer. How can I implement an endianness swap function?

Comment: Wouldn't `std::reverse` work, or am I missing something huge?

Comment: @chris: Endian-ness determines what the most significant *byte* is.

Comment: @chris: I think that would reverse the whole sequence and endianness only ... swaps some bytes or something?

Comment: @tskuzzy, Crap, my mind is numb from it being June >.>

Comment: @DeadMG, how about `std::rotate`? You could move around a group of bits.

Comment: By array of bits, do you mean arrays of 0's and 1's, each represented by an `int`, or by a packed array like a bitset?

Comment: @tskuzzy: It's actually a pointer to an expression which yields that bit later on. So you can forget unpacking the array into an actual unsigned integer or something, because there's no way to determine the values of the bits in question.

Comment: @DeadMG: So the smallest unit of your data is a *bit* and not a *byte*, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really a C++ person, so I'm just going to do this generically.

To convert from big endian to little endian is to reverse the bytes. That is, a segment of 8 bits.

So if you have an array of `N` bytes (pseudocoded here):

```
bool bits[8*N];
```

You will do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        bool tmp = bits[8*i+j];
        bits[8*i+j] = bits[8*(N-i-1)+j];
        bits[8*(N-i-1)+j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

In the comments, you mentioned that the "bits" are really pointers to expressions which are evaluated to the correct bits later. Well changing the order of the pointers in this fashion will yield the correct change of endian-ness when you later get the bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this excellent [article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/writing-endian-independent-code-in-c-r2091), where everything is explained on how to swap and handle data in different endianness. 
Also maybe the set of functions [endian.h](http://linux.die.net/man/3/endian) could be helpful for you.